# VB Script to show file name

Tags: file, vbscript, location, filenames

I have a file location set up that receives a new file everyday.  The file name is the same everytime with the exception of the date. For example the name is :  dog.AP.20150107.12345.col.531079.htm.   So every day I should have a new file where the date and the numbers after the col. are different.  How do I use a VB script to check if a new file is there and show me the name of the file? I am very new to using scripting and not sure what I need to include for this.  Any help would  be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this. You could for instance check the [`DateCreated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6a7czx%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) or [`DateLastModified`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xh895w%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property of the files:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\your\folder").Files
  If f.DateCreated > Date Then
    WScript.Echo f.Name
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Or you could check the date in the filename using the [`InStr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29) function:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

today = Now
d = Year(today) & Right("00" & Month(today), 2) & Right("00" & Day(today), 2)

For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\your\folder").Files
  If InStr(f.Name, d) > 0 Then
    WScript.Echo f.Name
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Please don't lure people into using the volatile Now() more than once in an expression.

Comment: Only if you promise not to use trailing empty parentheses ;þ